# Calculate where a geodesic line crosses a meridian

Tags: algorithm, spherical-geometry, geodesy, geodesic

Given a geodesic line between two points with known coordinates on a sphere, is there an easy way to calculate or approximate where this line crosses a specific meridian?

I want to calculate where the **shortest path** between P1 and P2 crosses a meridian. So far all the documentation I found was either above my math level or would take me ages to work through, [GEODESICS ON AN ELLIPSOID - BESSEL'S METHOD](http://www.mygeodesy.id.au/documents/Geodesics%20-%20Bessel%20method.pdf) for example.

Comment: Where have you looked and have you found another (not easy) way to do this?

Comment: "Easy way" and "geodesic" aren't really compatible.

Comment: Thanks, I have added some more info to my question.

Comment: The question is a bit general and its answer could be a more or less detailed repetition of the content of the [Geat-Circle_navigation Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_navigation). It would seem better if you have any specific doubt about any particular calculation of those involved in solving the problem, or the interpretation of a particular variable, that you ask about it.

Comment: An iterative approach could work, with a binary search algorithm and a tolerance, but this would be computationally expensive, since a geodesic Forward is already an iterative solution to the partial differential equation.